# Present Local notification without vibration in iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uilocalnotification

I want to present UILocalNotification with custom sound. But i don't want vibration while present the local notification.

It is possible?

Answer (score 1):

Vibration is always triggered if a sound is specified for the notification ( dependent on the user's settings, they may have Vibration turned off). I don't think there's currently any way of disabling vibrate for a sound-enabled notification.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to phone to only vibrate on receipt of a UI notification, you need to have a silent sound file in your application bundle, for example "silence.aif" ... if you specify that sound file in the notification, the iOS device will "play" the silence.aif from your application bundle, but since the sound is silence, there is nothing to hear.